# AngularJS: Loading controller before the view

Tags: angularjs

i am using in front side AngularJS and in the back Spring.
when i try to get my first or other page, scopes appear like that `{{user.fName+' '+user.lName}}` in a few seconds its replace with there values.

I want that scope appear directly with there values

Comment: What has spring to do with this? What is the exact issue? Why is it displaying after a few seconds?

Comment: i am talking about angularJS not spring, i dont know why, i think this happen because the app load the view first and then the controller

Comment: Give a look on [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: thank u, i solved the problem by adding ng-clock to the section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific with what you meant by "my first or other page scopes "

Do you mean that initially you get curly braces with angular code - which after a few seconds changes to the actual angular values? If that is the case you need to use `ng-cloak` in the containing html element. Please refer to the angular JS documentation.

Comment: this is exactly what happen, where i have to use ng-cloak

Comment: Use `ng-cloak` as follows The containing div should have the ng-cloak attribute. The code I have provided is just an example.  `<div ng-cloak>{{user.fName+' '+user.lName}}</div>`  Do mark this as the answer if correct.